# css border-left 50% height

Tags: css, border

I want the left border of my div to show only to the half of the div. The same I would like to do to my right border but is should be set from the bottom of the div to the middle of the div. How can I achieve it?

Comment: you cannot do this directly. there are several ways to solve this. but first, do you have a fixed width and/or height?

Comment: You'll have to fake it. Images, js, fake divs...

Comment: yes, it's a fixed width. I know I can do this by specifying some Images etc. and how can I do this by using JS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Good question. It's not possible using the border property.

The only thing that comes to mind, if you can set your div's `position` to `relative`, is to use an absolutely positioned, 1 pixel wide `div`. Not thoroughly tested but this *should* work:

```
<div style='width: 1px; top: 0px; bottom: 50%; left: 0px; 
            background-color: blue; overflow: hidden'>
 &nbsp;
</div>
```

You'd do the same on the right hand side, replacing the `left` property by `right`.

Remember, the surrounding `div` needs to be `position: relative` for this to work. I'm not sure about whether the 50% height setting will work consistently throughout browsers - make sure you test it. You may have to resort to pixel measures if it doesn't.

Comment: This only works if you set position: absolute; on the child div. The way your answer is written, if there's other content within the parent div, the child div will be placed relative to that other content.

Answer (score 62):

A sort-of similar but different approach to @Pekka's: use the `:after` pseudo-selector, like so:

```css
.mybox {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.mybox:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0000CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  Le content de box.
</div>
```

...and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yGQD/) for good measure.

Comment: Side note, as this is one of my more popular answers: you can also use the `:before` pseudo-selector if you want. Dealer's choice. The only reason I used `:after` here is because I enjoy visual hierarchy, so the _thing at the bottom_ goes `:after`.

Answer (score 19):

**2018:** For **modern browsers**:

You can use `border-image` with gradients something like...

```css
border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
border-image-slice: 1;
```

[image]

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/hz8wp0L0/

**Tool:** [Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+25,000000+75&0+24,1+25,1+75,0+76)

**Can I Use :** [border-image](https://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) *(IE11)*

Answer (score 15):

For those trying to implement Aleksandr Belugin's answer above using border-left, here it is:

```css
.mybox {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.mybox:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #0000CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  Le content de box.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
line-height:50%; /*(or less, much less)*/
overflow:visible;
```

The text is visible, but the border color will be only at half of the div size.

Answer (score 0):

*besides from using `::after`, as other answer posts shown*

---

#### solution

use `background` 
+ `linear-gradient` (img) 
+ position & size the `linear-gradient` (img)

- (to understand, read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#formal_syntax )

```css
.alpha {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5) 0%, rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.5) 50%, rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5) 100%) 0 50% / 5px 60% no-repeat;
  /* 
  linear-gradient(180deg, 
    rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5) 0%, 
    rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.5) 50%, 
    rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5) 100%) 
  - from top to bottom, 
    starts at position 0% with light grey 
    and middle stops at position 50% with dark grey 
    and ends at position 100% with light grey
  0 50% / 5px 60%
  - position start from left 0, from top 50%
  - size with 5px width, 60% height
  no-repeat
  - so that the img (linear-gradient) doesnt repeat to fill out the background 
    -- so that the position & size works
  */
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="alpha">aaaa<br>aaaa<br>aaaa<br>aaaa</div>
```

---

#### solution 2

or use `::before / ::after` with `inline-block`

*(you need to convert the jsx style to css..)*

```
        '&::before': {
          // display: 'inline', // must, or use relative // empty space content can but cannot percentage height?...
          content: '" "',
          display: 'inline-block',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          height: '0.8em',
          borderLeft: '1px solid #0000CC',
          padding: '0 0.8em 0 0',
        },
```

---

#### related

[How to create linear gradient only on left border and normal border for other 3 sides with content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349201/how-to-create-linear-gradient-only-on-left-border-and-normal-border-for-other-3) (good resource)

[Border left gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155885/border-left-gradient)