# Style a textarea with half border

Tags: html, css, textarea

how can I do a textarea to have a half border and to look just like the one from image below? and all this only with css.

[image]

In my html looks like :

```
    <div class"textareaKeeper">
    <textarea class="forDesc">Small Description</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a fixed width and a background image

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837440/css-border-left-50-height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to shift the textarea upwards and adjust for margins and paddings.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/76yza/11/) (fixed for browser inconsistencies).

```css
textarea {
    width: 198px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    top: -12px;
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
div {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 204px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea {
 border-top: 0;
 height: 18px; /* optional but looks like you have a short text area */
}
```

Comment: Also fails to address the PARTIAL borders on the left and right

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.forDesc{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white red red red;
}
```

If you want to achieve half border it's not possible with direct CSS border property

may be this can help you [css border-left 50% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837440/css-border-left-50-height)

Comment: OP is looking for a half-height border on the sides.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `span` or `div` inside the parent div and make it `position:absolute` and add the border

**HTML**

```
<div class="textareaKeeper">
    <textarea class="forDesc">Small Description</textarea>
      <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea{
    border:none; 
    height:30px;
    background:#fcf7d1;
    bottom:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:100%
}
span{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; display:inline-block;
     border-bottom:solid 1px red;
    border-left:solid 1px red;
    border-right:solid 1px red;
    height:15px
}
.textareaKeeper{
    border:none;   
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nEw2D/1/)**

Comment: forget to add `left: 0;` for `span`..??

Comment: @DipeshParmar left:0 is the default value of absolute

Comment: if is it so then why its not working in your fiddle...? why do i need to add `left : 0;` to make it work.???

Comment: @DipeshParmar My demo is working fine. the left space is the body margin not div space. Look @ this demo I have added border to parent div to show it http://jsfiddle.net/nEw2D/2/