# border only half the side of a div

Tags: html, css, border

[image]

In the  html div shown above I want a border on only some of the right-side of the div, however border-right sets a border for the whole side.

I have seen many other questions on this topic but the only working answers I have found require using a second div, but I want to know if this can be done without a second div, i.e: by editing the css properties of this div only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css border-left 50% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837440/css-border-left-50-height)

Comment: well it suggests the same approach as other question but i guess i will have to use another div as no better method seems to exist.

Comment: For all those said no please search for a while for solution don;t detract the user, have a look at my answers for knowledge  Thanks,

Comment: Check well all the answer, a lot them doesn't use any extra div

Comment: @TemaniAfif The question [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box) don't answer completely this question. It answer the question how to handle the height of the border but not his position according to the box. If you look closer, the border has to exceed the box by half of his width and this part is not explain in the 'duplicate'. So it would make sense to reopen this question.

Comment: @johannchopin check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103289/8620333 I am detailing all the cases, you can have any length and any position you want (and with no extra element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by adding a second div you mean no write it in the `html` you can simply use the `::after` css property on your div like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  right: -3px;
  height: 60%;
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That's the way I would do it as well.

Answer (score 2):

> By using pseudo code you can achieve your desire result, please have a look

```css
.wrap{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px; 
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
}
.wrap::after {
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    width: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    background: black;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">lorem</div>
```

Comment: Be aware if you look closer you will see that your border is only on the inside of the div. On the picture you can see that the border must be equally inside and outside :)

Comment: Set right to `-1px` gives that result

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's just css:

```css
.addBorder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.addBorder:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5);
  transform: scaleY(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="addBorder"></div>
```