# How can i make a border-left taking not 100% of left border, but smaller in height?

Tags: html, css

```css
#thirdcolumnfooter {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fourthcolumnfooter {
  padding-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: #EAAC00;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thirdcolumnfooter">

  <div class="container">
    <h5>FAST SHIPPING</h5>
  </div>

</div>


<div data-element_type="column" id="fourthcolumnfooter">

  <div class="firstrow">
    <h5>YOUR CART</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="secondrow">
    <span>VIEW CART</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

On the first picture there is what i have for now:

[image: border1]

On the second picture there is what i want to have - smaller hight of visible border, let it be 50 % or, for example, the same height as a div with "secondrow" class:

[image: border2]

I've seen this question - [css border-left 50% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837440/css-border-left-50-height) but this is not my case...And by the way i cannot remove the padding-right and padding-left from code - i use it for adding some space between columns.

Thanks

Comment: Try to add a left border on the .secondrow div and adjust it with css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Comment: So finally i really added left border to a div with class "secondrow" and also added some css like ```margin-left : -25%;``` and ```padding-left: 25%;``` and removed the old border. Yeah, simple and working. Thank you, Sfili_81, though other guys adviced also good things, your approach was the simplest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my idea, you can add a absolute positioned div to the height you want and then add the required border.

```css
#thirdcolumnfooter {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fourthcolumnfooter {
  padding-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.temp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: #EAAC00;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thirdcolumnfooter">

  <div class="container">
    <h5>FAST SHIPPING</h5>
  </div>

</div>


<div data-element_type="column" id="fourthcolumnfooter">

  <div class="firstrow">
    <h5>YOUR CART</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="secondrow">
    <span>VIEW CART</span>
  </div>
  <div class="temp"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Naren, your example is original and also working

Answer (score 1):

My proposition to wrap your html in another root div to make sure, if you add more content on your page, that will not affect to your current container. And the line will be represented by div class="border".

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
#thirdcolumnfooter {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fourthcolumnfooter {
  padding-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.border {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 5px;
  border-color: #EAAC00;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div #root>
  <div id="thirdcolumnfooter">

    <div class="container">
      <h5>FAST SHIPPING</h5>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="border"></div>
  
  <div data-element_type="column" id="fourthcolumnfooter">

    <div class="firstrow">
      <h5>YOUR CART</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="secondrow">
      <span>VIEW CART</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```