# Add a line (placeholder) before the element in DOM on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fluentui-react

I'm trying to add dotted line between the current element and previous element when draggable hovers over element as in image. Note the RED dot (manually added in image) placeholder before the yellow color element. It is in middle of two.

I tried border-left and border-image and border-image-slice discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399330/1881995, but these are giving feeling of left border, I need to place it slightly more over mid.

Could you please suggest CSS or other ways to achieve this?

[image: note the dot placeholder before the yellow color element]

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot place a block level element between them and apply the (red) dashed border to that element on hover?

Comment: I'm new to CSS. These are elements in grid (Stack), would you mean to insert a new element with id between items in grid? And on hover, access that element with id to apply dashed border?

Comment: Yes - exactly what I mean.

Comment: Using this stack - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/stack, It would be like adding new element in stack? Affects lots of size calculations? When I added extra divs before and after the stack-item, I think it is not what we want it sticks to item and highlighting it is not giving feel of what we want.

Comment: I've added the fluent-react tag to your question as that makes this quite specific. You might want to mention fluentUI in your question.

Comment: If I understand well you need something like this: https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/oNMezJg?editors=0010

If that's a solution you are looking for I can answer.